# Python Tools for Visual Studio 2013 Refreshing DB Issue

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, ptvs

I would like to use [Python Tools for Visual Studio 2013](https://pytools.codeplex.com/releases)

I have installed Annaconda Python Distribution 64bit. I have VS 2013 Ultimate. When I try to refresh the DB in the Python Tools it gets like 60% progress and then stops. After that the DB isn't refreshed and I need to start all over again. Without the refresh the completion doesn't really work ;/ Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in PTVS 2.1. It has been fixed in [PTVS 2.2](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/releases/v2.2).

Specifically, a recent change in one of the libraries included in Anaconda exposed a stack overflow in our code analysis that we had never seen before.

Comment: That is correct, installing PTVS 2.2 fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are on PTVS2.2 this can be fixed by going to Python Environments and clicking the refresh button as below:

[image]